# How to Create new Excel file out from seleniumRC result?

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-rc, data-driven

I'm creating a test case using selenium RC.
The General flow of the process is to get data from an Excel File.
Then run the SeleniumRC.

To get the result I place a printout command. All output is visible in the console. (using eclipse)

What I need to do next is to store all this data into a new Excel File. Can anyone help me on how to generate my output into an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Store the result in variables and then write them into the excel using the Java Excel API.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jexcel API.This link may be useful to you.
 http://r4r.co.in/java/apis/jexcel/

Answer (score 0):

A simply way I will suggest is to append all the printout statements in a storage variable like string buffer(Java) with delimiters like `|` symbols at the end of each line and then write this information into a text file.(line by line by split with the help of | symbols)

If you want to store this information in excel you will have to use the Apache POI Project to write data into excel sheets.(http://poi.apache.org/)